# How do you change the cursor type per div?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Is there anyway to change the pointer cursor to the "not-allowed" cursor in the div or GridList component in reactJS or material UI?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to add the code which you have tried, expected output and the output you are getting. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the css just add `cursor: not-allowed;` to the correct class/id of the div/element.

See more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp).